# Convert .xls to .csv

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, cmd

I need to convert an excel spreadsheet to a csv file. I would like to do the autonomously as opposed to opening it and save as manually. As I'm trying to incorporate this into a batch file I would also like to not have to install anything. I am using Excel 2007.

I've searched throughout this site and others but have been unable to come up with a complete solution yet. I found this vbs code on here from another question, so thanks to whomever got me started.

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
set oBook = oExcel.WorkBooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

The issue I'm running into is on the oExcel.WorkBooks.Open(src_file). I continually get errors that it's "Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks" error code 800A03EC.

Research into that error leads to people having issues with code on their servers, and the fixes people suggested did not work. This is not on a server, I'm trying to run it client side on a local file. I tried the script with a different excel file and it works perfectly. The difference with this one seems to be that when I open it I get the security alert from Office File Validation.

So any thoughts as to how to skip the Office File Validation warnings when opening via script?

Comment: What happens when you use File > Save As > CSV?

Comment: what string returns `src_file variable` in error line?

Comment: I'm also using a very similar version of that script.  Is it possible that the Excel file has different permissions?  More than one worksheet?  Did you try using the UNC path (I only say that because my version of the script runs flawlessly using UNC).

Comment: @JamesJenkins When I convert it manually in excel it's fine, the file saves perfectly. As I'm understanding the problem that's due to me clicking ok to get past the security warning. In fact I tried saving the file as a xlsx and the script ran perfectly.

Comment: @KazJaw I tried
`WScript.echo "source file "+src+" || "+variable`
and it returned "source file C:\test.xls || "

Comment: @Andrew I just checked the permissions and they are the same between the xls file I'm trying to convert and the xlsx one I saved manually. The only difference I can see is that the xls file is showing that the owner is Administrators while the other doesn't even have an owner field.

Comment: @Andrew I also just tried using UNC for the the arguments, but got the same results. It works just as great for the xlsx file, but the xls file is giving the same error message

Comment: Here's a registry fix for the Office Validation:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/671077-permanent-fix-office-validation-warning-offile-file-validation-detected-problem-while-trying-open-file.html